# Is it undefined behavior to have two pointers with different values referring to the same object?

Tags: c++, operating-system, undefined-behavior, memory-address

**Note**: if after reading this question you think, "how can that even happen", that is ok. If you want to keep an open mind, there are some points after the question that you can follow and that show how this can happen and why this is useful. Just remember that this is just a question and not a tutorial on any of these topics. The comments have enough noise already and they are hard to follow. If you have questions about these topics, I would appreciate if you post them as questions in SO instead of in the comments.

---

---

**Question**: If I have an object of type `int` stored at the address pointed by `c`

```
int* c = /* allocate int (returns unique address) */;
*c = 3;
```

referred by two pointers `a` and `b`:

```
int* a = /* create pointer to (*c) */;
int* b = /* create pointer to (*c) */;
```

such that:

```
assert(a != b);  // the pointers point to a different address
assert(*b == 3);
*a = 2;
assert(*b == 2);  // but they refer to the same value
```

Is this undefined behavior? If yes, which part of the C++ standard disallows this? If not, which parts of the C++ standard allows this?

**Note:** the memory `c` points to is allocated with a memory allocation function that returns an unique address (`new`, `malloc`, ...). The way to create these pointers with different values is very platform specific, although in most unix systems it can be done with `mmap` and on windows it can be done with `VirtualAlloc`.

---

---

**Background**: most operating systems (those that have a userspace that is not on ring 0) run their processes on virtual memory, and have a map from virtual memory pages to physical memory pages. Some of these systems (Linux/MacOS/BSDs/Unixes and 64bit windows) provide some system calls (like `mmap` or `VirtualAlloc`) that can be used to map two virtual memory pages to the same physical memory page. When a process performs this, it can essentially access the same page of physical memory from two different virtual memory addresses. That is, those two pointers will have a different value, but they will access the same physical memory storage. Keywords to google for: `mmap`, virtual memory, memory pages. Data-structures that use this feature for profit are "magic ring buffer"s (that's the technical term), and non-reallocating dynamically-sized vectors (that is, vectors that do not need to reallocate memory when they grow). Google provides more information about these than I could ever fit here.

**Very minimal probably non-working example (unix only)**:

We first allocate an int on the heap. The following request an anonymous, non-file-backed, mapping of virtual memory. One must request here at least a whole memory page, but for simplicity I'll just request the size of an `int` (`mmap` will allocate a whole memory page anyways):

```
int* c= mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_NONE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE,-1, 0);
```

Now we need to map this to two independent memory locations, so we map it to the same memory-mapped file, twice, to, e.g., two adjacent memory locations. We won't really use this file, but we still need to create it and open it:

```
mmap(c, sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_FIXED | MAP_SHARED, some_fd, 0);
mmap(c + 1, sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_FIXED | MAP_SHARED, some_fd, 0);
```

Now we are almost done:

```
int* a = c;
int* b = c + 1;
```

These are obviously different *virtual* addresses:

```
assert(a != b);
```

But they point to the same, non-file-backed, *physical* memory page:

```
*a = 314;
assert(*b == 314);
```

So there you go. Using `VirtualAlloc` the same can be done on Windows, but the API is a bit different.

Comment: Nothing here makes the smallest of sense

Comment: `c` has a unique address so all pointers to it will all contain that same unique address

Comment: `c` is not an object

Comment: `assert(b == 2);`  Is this the real code?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie that was a typo, should be fixed, it is a dereference.

Comment: @Amit: But `c` denotes an object.

Comment: *"how do you get this pointers, (...) has nothing to do with whether this is undefined behavior or not."* - That's incorrect.

Comment: Please provide code that reflects the actual problem you are trying to solve. It sounds like you're having an issue with two pointers of different types both pointing to the same object built using multiple inheritance. If that's the case you can use dynamic_cast (if it's polymorphic) to `void*` to get the absolute base pointer from both source pointers then check for equality.

Comment: You can't declare a variable via memory mapped files, or two virtual memory pages, and there is only one way to get its address. It is possible for two pointers to the same *object* to have different values, if one is declared as a pointer to a base type, but there are no objects here. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @NathanOliver sorry, now it should be fixed.

Comment: @gnzlbg Typing in `new int(3);` is shorter than `/* allocate int */;`.  So why you didn't officially allocate an integer, so that everyone understands what you're doing?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I would typically use `mmap` to allocate the memory when I want to `mmap` it again afterwards. Didn't want to introduce `mmap` till afterwards.

Comment: And the question is not `mmap` specific either so I also wanted to avoid mentioning `mmap` as much as I could.

Comment: @gnzlbg -- So the rules of C++ changes if the pointers to point to a mmap as opposed to just a regular `int`?

Comment: Since they put the question on hold, I can't post the answer I was about to submit, so here's the short version: Nothing in C or C++ itself would allow you to have two pointers referencing different virtual memory addresses that nevertheless are backed by the same "real" memory. They don't provide distinct concepts of virtual vs. physical memory that would be needed to have two virtual addresses map to the same backing storage. The closest you could come is defining a C++ iterator type that implemented `operator++` and related operators in such a way that it looped internally.

Comment: There is no way to create unequal pointers that point to the same object in a C++ standard compliant program. Since you must use non-standard implementation-specific techniques (memory mapped files or whatever), you should consult the implementation about how these techniques interact with standard C++ features. 

Technically, the C++ standard does not impose requirements on programs that use non-standard extensions provided by an implementation, so yes, any such program contains undefined behaviour.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I think I just fixed your issue by adding to "how do you get these pointers" that I am referring to a and b (and not c). Since `new` has to give you a unique address that leaves the door open for `c` being allocated by new. However, a and b can't be the result of allocations since they refer to `c`, so at least that part should be tight now.

Comment: Please people, if you don't understand the question, don't downvote or close it.

Comment: I agree with @n.m.; it's a matter of whatever library you're using, since mmap is not part of the core c++ standard. I'd suspect that you are indeed heading towards undefined behaviour, at least if you allow the c++ compiler optimisations (if aliasing can be a problem, I'm sure this stuff could be). However, I have not used mmap myself.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i don't know, do they? AFAIK `new` needs to give you a unique address, but I don't know in which sense `mmap` qualifies as allocating memory.

Comment: @NathanOliver pointed to a part in intro.memory before that might be useful here, something like all bytes should have an unique address. I would expect him to put that as an answer.

Comment: @gnzlbg *The memory available to a C++ program consists of one or more sequences of contiguous bytes. Every
byte has a unique address.*

Comment: @NathanOliver yes, I think that is the answer actually. That sounds pretty clear.

Comment: @gnzlbg  So your `/ *allocate int */` comment is a misnomer if you are not sure an int is really allocated.  All you know is that you got a pointer back from some entity.  That is *not* allocation, or at least what should be thought of as allocation.  If it were allocation, then the pointer value returned better be unique, or else you would have a ton of C++ programs breaking down left and right.

Comment: The pointer value returned by the allocation is unique. The first call to `mmap` just allocate memory and returns a pointer to it. It is the second and third calls that do the magic AFAIK.

Comment: Strange.. I answered a question very like this yesterday, (but it made more sense), but it now seems to have disappeared....

Comment: Does the C++ standard mandate virtual memory now??

Comment: 'Please people, if you don't understand the question, don't downvote or close it' - WHAT?  There is a specific 'unclear what you're asking' close-vote reason: 'Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.'  why not use it, if it's applicable, (which is surely is here)?

Comment: If two pointers in the same process point to the same object, they contain the same value.  There, that's it.  I can't see any need for more waffle abut virtual memory, mmap etc.

Comment: @MartinJames Using mmap (and other related techniques) one can, on every major unix os, and 64bit windows, get multiple pointers to the same object, with different values. If you don't agree, explain why. If you don't understand, say exactly what you don't understand. If you know a way to make the question more clear, please make a suggestion.

Comment: @gnzlbg OK, why did you tag this C++?  It's just an OS question re. pointers in different processes using  virtual memory management.   The Linux and Windows process management API's are C, calls, and C has no concept of classes and object instances.   You seem have overlapped two, mostly unrelated, concepts so as to disallow answers supplied in either.  This question has been edited 17 times now, and its still bad:(

Comment: @MartinJames First, the pointers exist in the same process. Second, I tagged this as C++ because I want to know if this is undefined behavior w.r.t. the C++ memory model. AFAIK modern C (>=11) also uses the same memory model as C++, so if this is UB in C++, it is likely also UB in C.

Comment: Funny thing is, I answered a question much like this one yesterday, but I cannot find it, or my answer, now:(

Comment: @MartinJames How can I improve the question? The system calls are well, system specific, but whether this is UB or not should be system independent (unless its implementation defined behavior).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First lets look at what the standard has to say about an object

> **[intro.object]**
>
> The constructs in a C++ program create, destroy, refer to, access, and manipulate objects. An object is a region of storage. [ Note: A function is not an object, regardless of whether or not it occupies storage in the way that objects do. —end note ] An object is created by a definition (3.1), by a new-expression (5.3.4) or by the implementation (12.2) when needed. The properties of an object are determined when the object is created. An object can have a name (Clause 3). An object has a storage duration (3.7) which influences its lifetime (3.8). An object has a type (3.9). The term object type refers to the type with which the object is created. Some objects are polymorphic (10.3); the implementation generates information associated with each such object that makes it possible to determine that object’s type during program execution. For other
> objects, the interpretation of the values found therein is determined by the type of the expressions (Clause 5) used to access them.

And then we have

> Unless an object is a bit-field or a base class subobject of zero size, the address of that object is the address of the first byte it occupies. Two objects that are not bit-fields may have the same address if one is a subobject of the other, or if at least one is a base class subobject of zero size and they are of different types; otherwise, they shall have distinct addresses.

So we know that an object has an address and it is the first byte of the storage it uses.  If we look at what a byte is we have

> **[intro.memory]**
>
> The fundamental storage unit in the C++ memory model is the byte. A byte is at least large enough to contain any member of the basic execution character set (2.3) and the eight-bit code units of the Unicode UTF-8 encoding form and is composed of a contiguous sequence of bits, the number of which is implementationdefined. The least significant bit is called the low-order bit; the most significant bit is called the high-order bit. The memory available to a C++ program consists of one or more sequences of contiguous bytes. **Every byte has a unique address.**

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

So if we have a pointer to an object the pointer is going to hold a unique value(address).  If we have another pointer to that same object then it will also have to have that same value(address).  Undefined behavior does not even enter the equation as you simply cannot have two pointers to the same object that have different values.

Comment: So if your implementation of address space allows obtaining non-unique addresses for the same byte and a program uses that, then what? I could interpret that as "they must behave as different objects" and thus it would be a bug in the implementation of C++'s memory model.

Comment: @gnzlbg: Undefined behaviour means the standard does not define how an implementation should behave in this case. That is not a "bug"; it just means that, if you `mmap` memory that way, you may not expect the implementation to handle that case "correctly", because "correct" *is not defined*.

Comment: @DevSolar but if I mmap memory such that some bytes have multiple addresses, I am breaking the assumption that every byte has a unique address. So i am basically on undefined behavior land, because the C++ standard only applies for when this is not the case. I think I am marking this answer as accepted, since the requirement that "every byte has a unique address" is as clear as it can possibly get.

Comment: @gnzlbg Thanks for that.  As far as I can tell what you are getting at is not defined by the standard.  The standard states every byte should have a unique address.  If that is violated then I believe that is UB.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To me this question is important because platform specific data-structures like dynamically-growing vector without memory reallocation rely on this to provide very low latency on `resize` and `push_back` (they never need to copy the buffer to some other buffer). Writing these data-structures is tricky, but if this is also UB one must also seek compiler support on these platforms to do this reliably (e.g. without the optimizer breaking your data-structures).

Comment: @gnzlbg: Your worries are correct. An optimizer which can prove that `a != b` may indeed assume that `*a=5` does not affect `*b`, and as a result optimize out reads of `*b`.The `volatile` keyword tells the compiler not to do this.

Comment: There are ways to break your programs besides Undefined Behavior, which has a specific meaning with regard to language constructs and the compiler's obligations to deal with them. When you mess around with memory mapping, you're outside that territory and it's on *you* to not screw up the compiler's assumptions about objects and pointers. As there are plenty of situations where memory can change other than under program control, or when writes can have side-effects, `volatile` is there for you to inform the compiler when something outside the language model is going on.

Answer (score 4):

The C++ standard does not define `mmap`, or any other method of mapping memory. The C++ standard only concerns about one way to view the memory. If the system uses virtual memory, then the standard is only concerned about virtual memory. No relation between virtual and physical memory is specified as far as I know.

What the standard says about memory:

> The memory available to a C++ program consists of one or more sequences of contiguous bytes. Every byte has a unique address.

What the standard says about objects:

> Unless an object is a bit-field or a base class subobject of zero size, the address of that object is the address of the first byte it occupies. Two objects that are not bit-fields may have the same address if one is a subobject of the other, or if at least one is a base class subobject of zero size and they are of different types; otherwise, they **shall have distinct addresses**.

So, when you ask:

> Is it undefined behavior to have **two pointers with different values referring to the same object**?

The two premises are contradictory. You can never have two pointers with different value referring to the same object. What you have is two different objects from the point of view of the standard. Even if the both virtual addresses are mapped to the same physical memory.

If we we're to assume that in the following code, the pointers `a` and `b` are magically mapped to same physical memory:

```
int *a, *b; // initialize with magic mapping of your choice
*a = 1;
if(a != b) {
    *b = 2;
    std::cout << *a; // what is the value of *a?
}
```

As far as the standard is concerned, `*a` and `*b` are different objects. They must be, because they have a different address. A compiler is free to optimize the reading of `*a` away and use the constant 1, because at no point between `*a = 1` and reading `*a`, is anything other than `*b` modified, which is an unrelated object.

So, if the compiler chooses to optimize, and use a constant, the output will be `1`. But, if the memory is actually read, and the virtual address is actually mapped to physical memory to which, `2` was just written, the output could be different. I don't know if it's explicitly undefined behaviour, but it's definitely unspecified at the very least.

Memory mapping is specified by the implementation, and so, the implementation specifies how memory mapped objects behave.

Comment: This makes sense. The free-store is part of the C++ runtime, and its behavior must be platform dependent by definition, so the behavior of mapping from virtual memory to physical memory have to be implementation defined since not all platforms have this mapping.

Comment: Variation of the same: `int* a; float* b` - again the compiler _knows_ that `*b=5.0` cannot affect `*a`. C++ is defined in terms of the possible behavior of an abstract machine, and if your real machine doen't match one of those possible machines you have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly allowed to have two different pointers pointing to the same object, under the condition that they have the same type than
the original object.  Nothing prevent this and it's certainly not undefined behaviour.

What is undefined behaviour is when you don't respect the [strict aliasing rule](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html), i.e. you have two pointers of different type refering to the same object. This is stated in the standard, section 3.10/10.  But it's not the case of your example.

Now the difficult part of your question:  can you have two pointers of different value that point to the same object ?

- Pointer management is implementation defined. On some older CPU architectures, compiler used memory models making use of [segment registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation) and offset registers.  Both are then combined to find out which unique address in memory they refer to.  Depending on how the pointers were stored, e.g.if they were stored as the juxtaposition of segment and offset, you could indeed have two pointers of different value pointing to the same object.
- However by definition of the equality operator (standard, section 5.10/3),  two pointers pointing to the same object are equal.  And this shall be true regardless of how the compiler implements the pointers (i.e. even if the bitwise value would be different, the comparison should return true if they refer to the same object)

Comment: 5.10 Says "Two pointers of the same type compare equal if and only if they are both null, both point to the same function, or both represent the same address". They do not represent the same address, but they refer to the same object. As @NathanOlivier points in the comments, [intro.memory.1] says: "The memory available to a C++ program consists of one or more sequences of contiguous bytes. Every byte has a unique address.".

Comment: 5.10/3 was a little more explicit, but it's true that it refers to members. But it's only a question of wording, because 1.8/6 tells us about the C++ object model that " Two objects that are not bit-fields may have the same address if one is a subobject of the other, or if at least one is a base class subobject of zero size and they are of different types; otherwise,they shall have distinct addresses"

Comment: To me that means that clause indicates when two objects shall have distinct addresses, but it doesn't really rule out that two distinct addresses cannot point to the same object. Maybe that wording was specifically chosen to allow this situation, but in that case they would have probably added a foot-note.

Comment: @gnzlbg: If I check `if ( &other != this )` in a copy constructor or an assignment operator, I check the *address* of `other` and `this`, and if they differ, I work under the assumption that `other` and `this` are two distinct objects. If your memory shenanigans allow for two distinct addresses to refer to the *same* object, that (valid) assumption is going to break, together with the program.

Comment: @DevSolar I see your point. There is a comment in [intro.memory.3] that requires bytes to have unique memory addresses.

Comment: @DevSolar thinking more about this, I think that whether the check `if(&other != this)` will fail or not if the same object is provided is implementation defined. I sadly don't know how the `this` pointer is exactly computed, but it can well be that `assert(a != b and &(*a) == &(*b));` works, because even though `a` and `b` have different values, they point to the same physical address. Dereferencing them obtains the physical value, and `&` might provide a _consistent_ way of computing a unique address to the physical value. _Iff_ this is UB, that doesn't need to work though. Very good point.

Comment: @gnzlbg: I think you're twisting your mind around the wrong thing here. If `a` and `b` point to the same physical address, `a != b` would be expected to return `false` for a conforming implementation.

Comment: @DevSolar But that is not the case on any operating system with virtual memory, which is about every operating system in use. Given two processes, both with one pointer, both of these pointers with the same value, _these pointers point to different physical memory addresses_. Otherwise you could overwrite the memory of one process from another. The difference here is just doing this within a single process. In particular, on any system with virtual memory `a != b` compares virtual memory addresses, not physical ones, unless your process is running in kernelspace (ring 0).

Comment: @gnzlbg: A program runs in *one* address space, and only ever gets to see that address space's virtual addresses (unless your memory abstraction layer is leaking abstraction like a sieve). ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar but because these address space is virtual, you can obtain pointers with different addresses that point to the same physical memory, so even though `a` and `b` point to the same physical address, they might have different virtual addresses. What are you comparing when you are doing `a != b`? Virtual addresses or physical ones?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105699/discussion-between-devsolar-and-gnzlbg).

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your hypothetical implementation is actually `assert(a != b);`

A simple thought experiment shows why. On the classic 8086, the two pointers `0000:0010` and `0001:0000` are **equal**, because both pointers refer to the same object. The implementation must ensure that these two pointers aren't compared bitwise.

In general, if your implementation allows two unique **bitpatterns** to refer to the same object, then those bitpatterns (interpreted as pointers) must compare equal.

You'll find that there are very few C++ implementations that contain a `mmap` function, though. That typically is an OS function, and the OS isn't bound by C++ rules. Calling OS functions tends to be UB anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to resort to MMU tricks to figure out how to construct two addresses that point to the same region of memory. There are segmented memory architectures, ARM Cortex bit-banding, etc. The C compiler isn't allowed itself to construct an object with two different addresses (this is actually nonsensical according to the way the language defines terms like "address" and "object") but the standard is written in such a way that it's expected that writing to some objects will cause things to happen as a side-effect, and that arbitrary other things other than your program writing to an object may change its value between reads. You're expected to know about these and mark them as `volatile`, though.

So your situation has nothing to do with Undefined Behavior; UB is part of the contract between programmer and compiler that says how the compiler is constrained (or not) by the programmer's use of the language. If you go *outside* the language, you can arbitrarily screw things up if you don't know what you're doing, but this has nothing to do with the compiler's obligations to you with regard to the standard. In this case, you have simply created two `volatile` objects that happen to be linked via side-effects to contain the same data. This is not a strange situation at all in the world of device drivers and memory-mapped registers!

Comment: Thanks! The analogy with volatile really makes sense. I guess that if I mark the two pointers returned by `mmap` as "a pointer to volatile `int` then I would be definetly on the safe side, since the compiler must assume that the memory that pointer points to might change between accesses.

Comment: Which makes me wonder, shouldn't `mmap` return a `volatile` pointer instead? Edit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207628/why-doesnt-posix-mmap-return-a-volatile-void

Comment: You can always assign an unadorned pointer to a volatile pointer, but you can't refer to an object defined with the `volatile` qualifier via a non-qualified pointer; this is undefined behavior. Since there are many uses for mmap that don't involve concurrent access to the mapped memory, it's up to the programmer to ensure the right `volatile` qualifier annotations to preserve the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Having pointers to each of two or more addresses which identify the same region of storage, and modifying the object using either of them, would create a situation equivalent to that of having an implementation modify the storage underlying an object behind the compiler's back for any other reason.  One should not expect any particular behavior unless both pointers are of a `volatile`-qualified type, but if both pointers are thus qualified behavior should be as expected on most implementations.  The Standard doesn't specify exactly what the effect of `volatile` should be, but nor does it define any means by which the situation you describe could exist.  Implementations in which the situation you describe could exist will generally document a means of ensuring that volatile reads or writes will physically access the region of address space identified by the pointer, and that all such accesses will be performed in the order given, but the Standard does not require that a `volatile` qualifier will necessarily be sufficient.

Note that even when `volatile` accesses are sequenced relative to each other, implementations might not sequence them relative to non-`volatile` accesses.  It would be helpful if there were a means by which a compiler could be told to write a bunch of information in any order, and then only write to a `volatile` location after all the other writes were complete, but there is no standard means of doing that except perhaps to make all of the data `volatile` (which would limit optimization opportunities, and may or may not be sufficient anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible using multiple inheritance, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A { int a; };

class B { int b; };

class C : public A, public B { };

void f(A &a) { cout << &a << endl; }

void g(B &b) { cout << &b << endl; }

int main() {
    C c;
    f(c);
    g(c);
}
```

which produces something like:

```
0x7fff5aba2878
0x7fff5aba287c
```

Now you can encapsulte mechanism to obtain the same shared value in the child class C:

```
class A {
  int a;
public:
  virtual int getValue() { return a; }
  virtual void setValue(int v) { a = v; }
};

class B {
  int b;
public:
  virtual int getValue() { return b; }
  virtual void setValue(int v) { b = v; }
};

class C : public A, public B {
  int c;
public:
  virtual int getValue() { return c; }
  virtual void setValue(int v) { c = v; }
};

void f(A &a) {
  cout << &a << endl;
  cout << a.getValue() << endl;
  a.setValue(5);
  cout << a.getValue() << endl;
}

void g(B &b) {
  cout << &b << endl;
  cout << b.getValue() << endl;
}

int main() {
    C c;
    c.setValue(3);
    f(c);
    g(c);
}
```

In that case you can observe:

```
0x7fff51063860
3
5
0x7fff51063870
5
```

Where it look like there is two objects (in real one object with *two addresses*) but that share the same value.

Note, there is some info about how carefully you should consider address(es) of object on ISO faq [What special considerations do I need to know about when I use virtual inheritance?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance)

Comment: In this case you don't actually have the same object.  You have two sub objects where one of them has the same address as the main object.

Comment: No it is the same object, there is only one object in this program, but this object has different views, this is what super types are: views to objects. You may even create a super class above and prove that what you think are two objects are the same...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: See the other answers which quote the standard. A pointer to an object is the  _address_  of that objects first byte in memory. With your example, the two different pointers point to different bytes and therefore to different objects.

Comment: I agree that the standard is not clear about that point; but seriously instanciating a single object could lead to two objects?  Semantically, there is only one object (only one instanciation) but the implementation realizes it through a form of composition (that is not really my problem), what I observe is that the same object has different addresses. I my base types where polymorphic I could be able to dynamic cast and travel across the type graph on the single object and obtain different addresses for the same object. Whatever, what is the address of my instanciated object?

Comment: There are two different senses of object here; one is the object-oriented sense meaning an instance of a class, and the other is the C sense, which is a region of allocated memory. They may be the same OO object, but they're different objects in the C sense because, having different starting addresses, they have different regions of allocation.

Comment: I know, this is the concept of "subobject"; in fact I don't like these mixed semantics.